# table 'users' already exists laravel when migrate laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, migrate

I'm having a problem when I run the migrate command, and I get the following message
Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists

Comment: Do a fresh migration (warning: existing data will be lost!) [Running Migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#running-migrations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Migration part of the up function, type this line at the beginning
if(Schema::hasTable('users')) return;

Answer (score 0):

This means that the migration process has encountered a pre-existing table with the same name in the database you're trying to migrate in. In this case, you can either delete **all** tables in your database manually *(Not recommended)*, or you can migrate with the `fresh` command so that it deletes all tables in your migration automatically to prevent issues with duplicate tables or constraints.

In your terminal, simply run:

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```

If that doesn't solve it, this might mean you have two migrations with the name "users", so go over all of your migrations and be sure no two classes contain a table creation line that looks like this:

```
Schema::create('users'...)
```